# C# How to write bytes into the middle of a byte[] array

Tags: c#, .net

The function ReadPipe() below reads chunks of bytes, and I need each chunk to go to the next location in byte[] packet_buffer.  But I can't figure out how to tell .ReadPipe to write bytes to within packet_buffer.

If it was C, I could just specify:   *packet_buffer[ byte index of next chunk ]

How do I do this in C#?

```
public static int receive_SetStreamPipe_2( byte[] packet_buffer,  int bytes_to_read )
    {
        uint received_chunk_bytes = 0;
        int remaining_bytes = bytes_to_read;
        int total_transferred_bytes = 0;


        // Use DataPipeInformation to get the actual PipeID             
        ftStatus = USB_device_selection0.SetStreamPipe( FT_pipe_information.PipeId, (UInt32)bytes_to_read );             
        if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)                 
                    return -(int)ftStatus;     // lookup:    FTDI.FT_STATUS



        // For each chunk 'o bytes:
        for(;;)
        {
            // Read chunk of bytes from FPGA:
                ftStatus = USB_device_selection0.ReadPipe( FT_pipe_information.PipeId, 
                                                            packet_buffer( remaining_bytes )  , <<<<<<<<<<<<<<  THIS WON'T WORK
                                                            (uint)remaining_bytes,
                                                            ref received_chunk_bytes );
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)                 
                        return -(int)ftStatus;     // lookup:    FTDI.FT_STATUS

            total_transferred_bytes +=  (int)received_chunk_bytes;
            remaining_bytes -=  (int)received_chunk_bytes;


            // Get more if not done:
            if( total_transferred_bytes <  bytes_to_read )
            {
                continue;  // go get more
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So create one buffer for each read, and copy that into a destination buffer?

Comment: 1. Create a bigger array, that can take both arrays together. 2. Use the CopyTo Method to copy the before, new, and after parts into the destination array. | As a  general rule, arrays can not grow or allow easy insertion. For such function, use a List[T].

Comment: Use a List object so you can append to the list.  Arrays you would need to resize to add more data.

Comment: @jdweng they know the size on beforehand and the array parameter to the method needs to be populated, and the parameter to the API needs to be an array as well. So a List would be an unnecessary extra variable.

Comment: Some methods in .NET have overloads for ArraySegments or Spans, maybe that could help you

Comment: Do you want to get an exception.  Unless you Absolutely know what your MAX buffer size is going to be it is safer to use a List.  What happens if your processor gets busy and the buffer size grows?

Comment: @jdweng it is not safer to use a list, using this API it is **impossible** to use a list. Every method ever that writes into an array, writes at most into that array the number of elements that you tell it to. You, as a caller, must make sure your array is large enough for that, and that's trivial to accomplish.

Comment: The is nothing wrong with using a list and code can easily be changed to accept a list.  It is better to be safe than to get an exception due to the buffer overflowing.

Comment: @jdweng there's nothing wrong with using arrays. You seem scared of arrays because they can overflow. They won't, if you write your code right. The OP may not be in the position to change the method signature.

Comment: @jdweng do you realise that your precious list class is implemented with an array?

Comment: An enhance array!!!  C# has limited array capabilities because you do not have pointers,  A c++ array implemented as a link link with pointers would be simple to add items to beginning, middle, and end of list.  We are dealing with c# and the best way of handling the managed memory is to use a list.

Comment: @CodeChaos It's quite funny though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on CodeCaster's response, the best answer so far is that I have asked the FTDI company that makes the USB host driver to provide an overload with an offset.

Answer (score -1):

Making the following assumption on your code, which I really shouldn't have to, please read [ask] and provide all relevant details:

- `receive_SetStreamPipe_2(byte[] packet_buffer, int bytes_to_read)`:

  - Is implemented by you
  - Receives in `packet_buffer` an array that is at least `bytes_to_read` long and needs to be filled with exactly `bytes_to_read` bytes
- `USB_device_selection0.ReadPipe(FT_pipe_information.PipeId, packet_buffer, (uint)remaining_bytes, ref received_chunk_bytes)`:

  - Fills `packet_buffer` from index 0 and doesn't have an overload with an offset (such as [`Stream.Write(buffer, offset, count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write?view=netframework-4.8))
  - Fills it up to at most `remaining_bytes`, but probably less
  - Assigns the `received_chunk_bytes` to how many bytes have been read

Then you need to introduce a temporary buffer that you copy to the final buffer. How large that buffer should optimally be should be obtainable from the API information, but let's take 1024 bytes:

```
uint received_chunk_bytes = 0;
int remaining_bytes = bytes_to_read;
int total_transferred_bytes = 0;

// Create a smaller buffer to hold each chunk
int chunkSize = 1024;
byte[] chunkBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];

// ...

for (;;)
{
    // Read chunk of bytes from FPGA into chunkBuffer, chunk size being the the buffer size or the remaining number of bytes, whichever is less
    ftStatus = USB_device_selection0.ReadPipe(FT_pipe_information.PipeId, 
                                              chunkBuffer
                                              (uint)Math.Min(chunkSize, remaining_bytes),
                                              ref received_chunk_bytes);

    if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)                 
                    return -(int)ftStatus;     // lookup:    FTDI.FT_STATUS

    // Copy the chunk into the output array
    Array.Copy(chunkBuffer, 0, packet_buffer, total_transferred_bytes, received_chunk_bytes);

    total_transferred_bytes +=  (int)received_chunk_bytes;
    remaining_bytes -=  (int)received_chunk_bytes;

    // ...
```

Comment: No offset overload (would solve the problem!).   Yes, I have been using temporary buffer which I want to eliminate because it degrades performance.  This answer does not answer the question:  how to write bytes in the middle of an array.

Comment: It does answer that question: _"if the API you use to write to the array doesn't support an offset, you can't, so here's a workaround"_. If that causes performance problems, then show the code you have and what problems there are exactly.

Comment: In other words: you have to pass a `byte[]` to that method and you can't pass an offset, so you cannot write to an arbitrary point into that array.

Comment: I really don't get the votes here. You may not like the answer "You can't", but it is an answer